# How to get iLife '13 for free (update from iLife '11)?

Tags: upgrade, ilife

I currently have iLife '11 installed on my iMac from a retail disk purchased new from eBay. Under the updates section of the App Store, there is nothing that says iLife Update.

I thought updates for iLife '11 to iLife '13 would be free?

Comment: Have you already checked all the stuff written about this last month, like http://www.macrumors.com/2013/10/22/some-users-with-older-copies-of-ilife-and-iwork-having-difficulties-upgrading-to-new-versions/

Comment: Have you upgraded to Mavericks? They didn't show for me until after I had upgraded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You thought right**, the update to new iLife is free.

However, Apple had dropped the "iLife" name a while ago, now the apps are just being called *iPhoto*, *iMovie* and *GarageBand*.

To get the new versions of the apps, follow these steps:

1. Upgrade to *Mavericks* via App Store. This requires **at least OS X 10.6.8** to be installed.
2. Change system preferred language to English and **reboot** your Mac.
3. Open App Store and search for *GarageBand*. It is free now, no matter if you had iLife before.
4. Go to **Updates** tab and wait for a minute. Newest versions of *iPhoto* (9.5) and *iMovie* (10.0) should appear.

Note, that even pirated and demo versions of *Pages*, *Numbers*, *Keynote*, *iMovie*, *iPhoto* and *Aperture* can be upgraded via App Store. They will appear in **Purchases** tab a **few minutes after** the upgrade.

**Troubleshooting**

- If you do not see a response to **Update** button click, check your
  *Launchpad*. Upgrades are downloading in background.
- If you are getting an error about wrong Apple ID when trying to
  upgrade, try installing **OS X Mavericks** in a virtual machine
  (*VMWare Workstation* or *VirtualBox*) and repeating the fourth step.

Comment: I have iLife 08. Is it possible to get the latest updates without first updated to iLife 11? Checking for updates manually brings me to a [broken link](http://www.apple.com/ilife/upgrade/).

Comment: If newer versions of iPhoto and iLife are not appearing in Updates tab in Mavericks App Store, remove 08 and download 11 from TPB and retry.

Comment: @styfle: the free upgrades are only available if you have the previous version of iLife ('11). For example, my wife's MacBook came with iLife '08 and the Mac App Store lists the new version of iPhoto as $15.